# Getting this error: ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, graphql

Trying to pull some data off GraphQL for Uniswap v3 and getting this error in this part of the code. I have included the error below along with the full code:

```
got exception __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowed_methods'
got exception while querying pool data: Transport is already connected
Querying ticks, num_skip=0
got exception while querying tick data: Transport is already connected
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-992884f81973> in <module>()
    115 
    116 # Find the boundaries of the price range
--> 117 min_tick = min(tick_mapping.keys())
    118 max_tick = max(tick_mapping.keys())
    119 

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

---

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport
import math

# 0.3% USDC/ETH pool
POOL_ID = "0x8ad599c3a0ff1de082011efddc58f1908eb6e6d8"

# If you want to test with a smaller pool:
# 0.05% GUSD/DAI pool (small pool)
#POOL_ID = "0x7cf12cef5ce9e5e068ebdef470ff8295e26c47b9"

URL = "https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3"

pool_query = """query get_pools($pool_id: ID!) {
  pools(where: {id: $pool_id}) {
    tick
    sqrtPrice
    liquidity
    feeTier
    token0 {
      symbol
      decimals
    }
    token1 {
      symbol
      decimals
    }
  }
}"""

tick_query = """query get_ticks($num_skip: Int, $pool_id: ID!) {
  ticks(skip: $num_skip, where: {pool: $pool_id}) {
    tickIdx
    liquidityNet
  }
}"""

block_query = """query {
  _meta {
    block {
      number
    }
  }
}"""
TICK_BASE = 1.0001

def tick_to_price(tick):
    return TICK_BASE ** tick

# Not all ticks can be initialized. Tick spacing is determined by the pool's fee tier.
def fee_tier_to_tick_spacing(fee_tier):
    return {
        500: 10,
        3000: 60,
        10000: 200
    }.get(fee_tier, 60)
client = Client(
    transport=RequestsHTTPTransport(
        url=URL,
        verify=True,
        retries=5,
    ))
# get current block height, for record
try:
    response = client.execute(gql(block_query))
    blocknum = response['_meta']['block']['number']
    print("Ethereum block height {}".format(blocknum))
except Exception as ex:
    print("got exception", ex)
# get pool info
try:
    variables = {"pool_id": POOL_ID}
    response = client.execute(gql(pool_query), variable_values=variables)

    if len(response['pools']) == 0:
        print("pool not found")
        exit(-1)

    pool = response['pools'][0]
    current_tick = int(pool["tick"])
    ft = int(pool["feeTier"])
    tick_spacing = fee_tier_to_tick_spacing(ft)

    token0 = pool["token0"]["symbol"]
    token1 = pool["token1"]["symbol"]
    decimals0 = int(pool["token0"]["decimals"])
    decimals1 = int(pool["token1"]["decimals"])
except Exception as ex:
    print("got exception while querying pool data:", ex)
    exit(-1)

pool
# get tick info
tick_mapping = {}
num_skip = 0
try:
    while True:
        print("Querying ticks, num_skip={}".format(num_skip))
        variables = {"num_skip": num_skip, "pool_id": POOL_ID}
        response = client.execute(gql(tick_query), variable_values=variables)

        if len(response["ticks"]) == 0:
            break
        num_skip += len(response["ticks"])
        for item in response["ticks"]:
            tick_mapping[int(item["tickIdx"])] = int(item["liquidityNet"])
except Exception as ex:
    print("got exception while querying tick data:", ex)
    exit(-1)
# Start from zero; if we were iterating from the current tick, would start from the pool's total liquidity
liquidity = 0

# Find the boundaries of the price range
min_tick = min(tick_mapping.keys())
max_tick = max(tick_mapping.keys())

# Compute the tick range. This code would work as well in Python: `current_tick // tick_spacing * tick_spacing`
# However, using floor() is more portable.
current_range_bottom_tick = math.floor(current_tick / tick_spacing) * tick_spacing

current_price = tick_to_price(current_tick)
adjusted_current_price = current_price / (10 ** (decimals1 - decimals0))

# Sum up all tokens in the pool
total_amount0 = 0
total_amount1 = 0

# Guess the preferred way to display the price;
# try to print most assets in terms of USD;
# if that fails, try to use the price value that's above 1.0 when adjusted for decimals.
stablecoins = ["USDC", "DAI", "USDT", "TUSD", "LUSD", "BUSD", "GUSD", "UST"]
if token0 in stablecoins and token1 not in stablecoins:
    invert_price = True
elif adjusted_current_price < 1.0:
    invert_price = True
else:
    invert_price = False

# Iterate over the tick map starting from the bottom
tick = min_tick
while tick <= max_tick:
    liquidity_delta = tick_mapping.get(tick, 0)
    liquidity += liquidity_delta
    
    price = tick_to_price(tick)
    adjusted_price = price / (10 ** (decimals1 - decimals0))
    if invert_price:
        adjusted_price = 1 / adjusted_price
        tokens = "{} for {}".format(token0, token1)
    else:
        tokens = "{} for {}".format(token1, token0)

    should_print_tick = liquidity != 0
    if should_print_tick:
        print("ticks=[{}, {}], bottom tick price={:.6g} {}".format(tick, tick + tick_spacing, adjusted_price, tokens))
    
    # Compute square roots of prices corresponding to the bottom and top ticks
    bottom_tick = tick
    top_tick = bottom_tick + tick_spacing
    sa = tick_to_price(bottom_tick // 2)
    sb = tick_to_price(top_tick // 2)
    
    if tick < current_range_bottom_tick:
        # Compute the amounts of tokens potentially in the range
        amount1 = liquidity * (sb - sa) # eq(9) in technical note
        amount0 = amount1 / (sb * sa) # eq(4) and eq(9) in technical note
        
        # Only token1 locked
        total_amount1 += amount1

        if should_print_tick:
            adjusted_amount0 = amount0 / (10 ** decimals0)
            adjusted_amount1 = amount1 / (10 ** decimals1)
            print("        {:.6g} {} locked, potentially worth {:.6g} {}".format(adjusted_amount1, token1, adjusted_amount0, token0))

    elif tick == current_range_bottom_tick:
        # Always print the current tick. It normally has both assets locked
        print("\n        ## Current tick, both assets present!")
        print("        Current price={:.6g} {}".format(1 / adjusted_current_price if invert_price else adjusted_current_price, tokens))

        # Print the real amounts of the two assets needed to be swapped to move out of the current tick range
        current_sqrt_price = tick_to_price(current_tick / 2)
        amount0actual = liquidity * (sb - current_sqrt_price) / (current_sqrt_price * sb) # eq(12) in technical note
        amount1actual = liquidity * (current_sqrt_price - sa) # eq(13) in technical note
        adjusted_amount0actual = amount0actual / (10 ** decimals0)
        adjusted_amount1actual = amount1actual / (10 ** decimals1)
        
        total_amount0 += amount0actual
        total_amount1 += amount1actual

        print("        {:.6g} {} and {:.6g} {} remaining in the current tick range\n".format(
            adjusted_amount0actual, token0, adjusted_amount1actual, token1))        
        
    else:
        # Compute the amounts of tokens potentially in the range
        amount1 = liquidity * (sb - sa)
        amount0 = amount1 / (sb * sa)

        # Only token0 locked
        total_amount0 += amount0

        if should_print_tick:
            adjusted_amount0 = amount0 / (10 ** decimals0)
            adjusted_amount1 = amount1 / (10 ** decimals1)
            print("        {:.6g} {} locked, potentially worth {:.6g} {}".format(adjusted_amount0, token0, adjusted_amount1, token1))

    tick += tick_spacing

print("\nIn total: {:.6g} {} and {:.6g} {} (not including accrued swap fees)".format(
      total_amount0 / (10 ** decimals0), token0, total_amount1 / (10 ** decimals1), token1))

current_adjusted_price = tick_to_price(current_tick) / (10 ** (decimals1 - decimals0))
print("At current price {:.6g} {} for 1 {} ({:.6g} {} for 1 {}),".format(
    current_adjusted_price, token1, token0, 1 / current_adjusted_price, token0, token1))

print("  equiv. to total liquidity {:.6g} {} or {:.6g} {}".format(
    (total_amount1/current_price+total_amount0)/(10**decimals0), token0,(total_amount0*current_price+total_amount1)/(10**decimals1),token1))
print("As at Ethereum block height {}".format(blocknum))
```

This section of the code seems to be the issue:

```
# Find the boundaries of the price range
min_tick = min(tick_mapping.keys())
max_tick = max(tick_mapping.keys())
```

Tried to change it to a list but not working, not sure how to fix. Maybe its due the mapping function?

Comment: `tick_mapping` is empty. How can you get the minimum key if there aren't any keys?

Comment: I want to get the min tick and the max tick of a pool too, did you manage to get them? how?